# For new test cases, how to stop the Tester field automatically defaulting to the name of whoever created the card?

Tags: testing, azure-devops

On creating a new test case in Azure DevOps, we've noticed the 'Tester' field is automatically set to the name of whoever created the card. This is incorrect, as testing on the card has not started and none of the QA team has picked it up yet. I imagine very few software companies have just one tester and instead have multiple people working through test suites once testing begins. So I imagine this must be an issue for other teams. How can the field be changed to show that no testers have yet been assigned and the test case is waiting to be picked up by one of the team?

n.b There doesn't appear to be any assigned rules at present, so nothing that I can go in and modify to stop automatically adding a name. And there is nowhere to edit the 'Tester' field. Even if you create a new template, when you try to edit that template the 'Tester' field still doesn't show up.

Tried asking this on Super User. Was advised to re-ask the question here.

Comment: Do you mean to the field "Assigned To"?

Comment: It's the column labelled 'Tester'. When you actually go into the test case itself, there is no field label. It automatically fills in a name (of the test creator) when the card is created. If you try to leave it blank, it prompts you for a recognised name.

Comment: Which process template do you use? can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Can you stop the antomatically default the assigner to whoever created the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the **Tester** column is **Assign to** field.

You can let the **Assign to** field blank while create the test case card. This is not a required field, so it can be empty and save the Test case. In addition, this field could not be modified in process.

While you want to reassign to someone to test it, right click it and choose **Assign tester**. Search the people you want to assign to.

[image]

> How can the field be changed to show that no testers have yet been
>   assigned?

[image]

After you let the Assign to field blank, and modify filter criteria **Tester** as Unassigned, you will see the test case list which has no testers been assigned.

> For how to show the test case is waiting to be picked up by one of the
>   team?

There's no direct UI to achieve that. But you can [modify the test suite assign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-test-cases?view=azure-devops#assign-testers) to achieve indirectly. Right click the Test suites, choose **Assign testers to run all tests**.

[image]

And then, add some testers from the list. After these, you can consider to send mail to these tester so that they can know here has some test cases are waiting for picked up. Tick the **Send email checkbox**, edit the message you want to notified.

[image]

Note:There is a **link** within the email which notify the tester be assigned. They can click it to see the list of assigned tests. These testers just need Basic access to run tests from Azure Test Plans.